# prevent ejs from splitting string in attribute-value pairs

Tags: ejs

I have an input tag like this:

```
<input id="nodename" class="form-control" placeholder=Enter node name" type="text">
```

Know I want to add a node name into the input, if one is given.

What I try is:

```
<div id="divForNodeName"><input id="nodename" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter node name" type="text" value= <%- node.name %> ></div>
```

While node is:

```
{
 name: "A node Name"
}
```

What I get is:

```
<div id="divForNodeName"><input id="nodename" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter node name" value="A" node="" name=""  type="text"></div>
```

But what I need is:

```
 <div id="divForNodeName"><input id="nodename" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter node name" value= "A node name" type="text"></div>
```

So I do not want the splits at the white spaces.
I tried the options `<%=`, `<%- -%>` and `<%-`
but both are not working.

Does someone see my mistake?

The ejs-version I am using is: https://github.com/mde/ejs

Answer (score 0):

It should be value= "<%- node.name %>"